# How many arguments do I need to provide to the scanner-cminor binary?

Tags: jack

I am trying to run the binary built from the makefile at https://github.com/johnmryan/scanner-cminor, but am getting the error message "Please provide the correct number of arguments."

I have checked all available documentation, but it does not say how many args I need to provide.

I see that commit `ddedbe1373ad65a3effc57fcb360b66e5e9437dc` is titled "Improved error handling" but I don't think that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One argument will do. This should be fixed in the [most recent update to the scanner](https://github.com/johnmryan/scanner-cminor/commit/fd4294218f01a207dc191753f12fd08366f00233)!